# How to update a cell in a list without "get" into it?

Tags: python, list

I have a question about lists. I have a 1 length list called `size`, `size=[4]`.

And I have a board, and some of the cells have `size` as a value among other values. I will explain:

- board is 17x17
- `board[x][y] = ("name_of_something", size)`

I want to update `size` to be, lets say, `[3]`, and I want that every cell that have `size` as value, will also update from `("name_of_something", [4])` to `("name_of_something", [3])`.

But I want to to this *without* running all over the board! How can I do this?

here is an image:
http://up400.siz.co.il/up2/utg4yidtnmz1.jpg

Comment: Make sure the cells all share the same list, then update that. (Or restructure your program, because this seems to be an X-Y problem.)

Comment: Might also use a dictionary `{size: [(x,y)]}`

Comment: When all cells have this value, and it’s supposed to be the same anyway for every cell, then why are you even storing this *inside* the cells? You could just store it externally instead.

Comment: Do you want to update sizes in cells with equal name or cells with equal size?

Comment: larsmans, yes! can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your image:

```
>>> size = [4]
>>> a = ('nadav', 3, size)
>>> size = [3]
>>> a
('nadav', 3, [4])
```

What you are doing is assinging a *new list* to `size` while `a` will still point to the old list. You have to modify the existing list instead:

```
>>> size = [4]
>>> a = ('nadav', 3, size)
>>> size[:] = [3]
>>> a
('nadav', 3, [3])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the board, just make sure that all the cells are referring to the same list.

See this for example:

```
size=[3]
n_rows=3
n_cols=3
board=[
  [('cell %d,%d'%(row,col),size) for col in range(n_cols)] 
  for row in range(n_rows)
]
print('Before:')
for row in board:
  print('  '+str(row))
size[0] = 4
print('After:')
for row in board:
  print('  '+str(row))
```

Result:

```
Before:
  [('cell 0,0', [3]), ('cell 0,1', [3]), ('cell 0,2', [3])]
  [('cell 1,0', [3]), ('cell 1,1', [3]), ('cell 1,2', [3])]
  [('cell 2,0', [3]), ('cell 2,1', [3]), ('cell 2,2', [3])]
After:
  [('cell 0,0', [4]), ('cell 0,1', [4]), ('cell 0,2', [4])]
  [('cell 1,0', [4]), ('cell 1,1', [4]), ('cell 1,2', [4])]
  [('cell 2,0', [4]), ('cell 2,1', [4]), ('cell 2,2', [4])]
```